# Handle socketio room broadcast under load balancer in flask

Tags: websocket, flask-socketio, amazon-elb

I have a flask API application with flask-socketio which connects with angular. The flask-socketio connection and broadcasts and rooms messages are working fine until when I run my app in only one instance on AWS. But when I run my flask application on two instances particularly under a load balancer, the socket events and messages are received to only particular users. It looks like the instance which got broadcast requests from the client/internal function is returning to the users connected to that particular machine.

How can I handle a state between two instances? Particularly, What should I do for sending broadcast messages to all the users?

As of now, the server is running on gunicorn and I'm not using any message queue on flask-socketio.

Comment: Have you read the documentation regarding running multiple instances of Flask-SocketIO and the requirements this has on the load balancer and the message queue?

Comment: Yes miguel as per documentation I'm running gunicorn with only one process on each instance

Comment: What message queue?

Comment: I'm not sure about it. As far as I know they are keeping all events at one place

Comment: You have to use a message queue. If you aren't using one, then that's the problem. The two instances need a way to communicate with each other.

Answer (score 0):

I tried several ways and came to the solution that we need to add `message_queue` with Redis(or similar) in order to share state(user ids in this case) between instances under a load balancer.

Make sure you install Redis

```
pip install redis
```

and add Redis URL to socketio message_queue

```
socketio = SocketIO(app, message_queue='redis://')
```